# IntegrityError at /api/course/ (1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hello everyone I need some help over this issue in Django I got when I tried to insert a new course

```
IntegrityError at /api/course/ (1048, "Column 'category_id' cannot be null")
```

Model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='teacher_courses')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()  
    featured_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='course_imgs/',null=True)
    techs = models.TextField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "3. Courses"   

    def related_content(self):
            related_content=Course.objects.filter(techs__icontains=self.techs)
            return serializers.serialize('json',related_content)     

    def tech_list(self):
        tech_list = self.techs.split(',')
        return tech_list 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

View:

```
class CourseList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
 
    queryset = models.Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer 

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if 'result' in self.request.GET:
            limit = int(self.request.GET['result'])
            qs = models.Course.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:limit]  
        
        if 'category' in self.request.GET:
            category = self.request.GET['category']
            qs = models.Course.objects.filter(techs__icontains=category)

        if 'skill_name' in self.request.GET and 'teacher' in self.request.GET:
            skill_name = self.request.GET['skill_name']   
            teacher = self.request.GET['teacher']   
            teacher = models.Teacher.objects.filter(id=teacher).first()
            qs = models.Course.objects.filter(techs__icontains=skill_name,teacher=teacher) 

        return qs
```

Serializer:

```
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = ['id','title','description','category_id','teacher','featured_img','techs','course_chapters','related_content','tech_list']
        depth=1
```

I have been searching the solution for hours but I did not get any way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

an integrity error is a database error, you're trying to enter a Course object without specifying (in your case) which CourseCategory object the Course Object is connected to. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/). You will have to choose an Existing CourseCategory to link the Course to.

Answer (score 2):

Problem resides in your `category` field in `Course` model.

```
 category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You have not assigned any `CourseCategory` object to your field. If that was a mistake you should assign a `CourseCategory` otherwise if you want to opt if `CourseCategory` can be accepted as `null` you should change that line to:

```
 category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Furthermore, you need to change your `category_id` in your serializer to `category`. If your serializer fields are not custom, they should match their respective model's fields names.

Comment: i have tride what you suggested and i could store a course but i dont want to store a course without both category and course. what i dont understand is why category value are not being posted while i supply it from my frontend app

Comment: Cant understand your problem, mind editing your post to further explain? Also add whatever code is needed

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by the `depth=1` inside CourseSerializer class to solve this I had to create 2 Serializers classes one for Inserting in database which does not contain `depth=1` and other for retreiving data form DB which contains `depth=1` because my `Course` Model has a relationship with a `Category` Model:

```py
class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = ['id','title','description','category_id','teacher','featured_img','techs','course_chapters','related_content','tech_list','total_enrolled_students']
        depth=1

class CourseInSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Course
        fields = ['id','title','description','category','teacher','featured_img','techs']
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've defined the depth, you now need to write your own creation and update the methods that will handle changing nested fields.

class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = models.Course
    fields = ['id','category','teacher','title','description','course_image','technologicals','course_chapters','related_courses','technological_list','total_enrolled_students']
    # depth = 1

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CourseSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    request = self.context.get('request')
    self.Meta.depth = 0
    if request and request.method == 'GET':
        self.Meta.depth = 1
```